# How to apply css on a specific div?

Tags: html, css

I've the following HTML

```
<form>>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="search-col"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="search-col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div>  
    </div>
</form>

<form>>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="search-col1"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="search-col1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div>  
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to over-ride the behaviour of `form-group` and `form-control` of class `search-col`, but not of `search-col1`. How can I do that?

this is what I'm trying

```
.form-group .form-control .search-col{
  outline: none;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-background-size: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition-duration: none;
}
```

Comment: not sure why you dont just use .search-col and .search-col1 since the classes are different

Comment: For reference, see [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information_Selectors_based_on_relationships). Specifically, `A E : Any E element that is a descendant of an A element (that is: a child, or a child of a child, etc.)`

Answer (score 2):

Your order is wrong on your selectors. It should be:

```
.form-group .search-col .form-control {...}
```

CSS targets in the order of the parent/child relationship of the DOM elements. This is basically saying style the .form-control class inside of the .search-col class that is inside of the .form-group class.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure does not match your CSS selector.

It should be:

```
.form-group .search-col { ... }
```

Or, for that matter, it could even be:

```
.search-col { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to style the individual containers? As others have pointed out ensure the order of the selectors is correct. You shouldn't really have to 'override' anything, as the styles are not the same in each section. I've included a sample image below.

```
.form-group {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-group {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: #abc;
}

/* Notice how each class gives a different style */
.search-col {
  background-color: #75AD63;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-col1 {
  background-color: #A1D490;
  background-origin: ;
  padding: 10px
}
```

If you want to override a specific element which is a child of another div, you can use the right angle bracket to select them like I did below. The image connected is the output.

```
.form-group > .search-col > .form-control {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Example Styling](http://imgur.com/MtsBK2t)

Notice how I didn't change the original style of the form-control class.